# Filter and simplify JSON output in R

Tags: r, json

I have a JSON output like this:

```
[
  {
    "search": {
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": ["1_3627688_C_T"],
          "rsId": ["rs182954137"],
          "mostSevereConsequence": ["intron_variant"],
          "nearestGene": {
            "chromosome": ["1"],
            "start": [3625015],
            "end": [3630127],
            "id": ["ENSG00000158109"],
            "symbol": ["TPRG1L"],
            "tss": [3625015],
            "description": ["tumor protein p63 regulated 1 like [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:27007]"],
            "bioType": ["protein_coding"],
            "__typename": ["Gene"]
          },
          "nearestGeneDistance": [2673]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "search": {
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": ["1_2909753_G_A"],
          "rsId": ["rs114818383"],
          "mostSevereConsequence": ["intergenic_variant"],
          "nearestGene": {
            "chromosome": ["1"],
            "start": [2636986],
            "end": [2801693],
            "id": ["ENSG00000215912"],
            "symbol": ["TTC34"],
            "tss": [2801693],
            "description": ["tetratricopeptide repeat domain 34 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:34297]"],
            "bioType": ["protein_coding"],
            "__typename": ["Gene"]
          },
          "nearestGeneDistance": [108060]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Is it possible to simplify the JSON file so it will be easier to view it in a browser ?

I created the file with

```
library(httr)
library('jsonlite')

# Set data with  rs_id variables
IDs <- c("rs182954137", "rs114818383")
# Build query string
query_string = "
  query useSearchToConvertRSIDIntoIDFormat($myVariantId: String!){
    search(queryString: $myVariantId){
      variants {
      id
      rsId
      mostSevereConsequence
      nearestGene {
        chromosome
        start
        end
        id
        symbol
        tss
        description
        bioType
        __typename
      }
      nearestGeneDistance
        }
      }
    }
"
# Set base URL of Genetics Portal GraphQL API endpoint
base_url <- "https://api.genetics.opentargets.org/graphql"
#set function and code for multiple ensemblIDs 
alldata <- lapply(IDs, function(rs_id) {
  # Construct POST request body object with query string and variables
  post_body <- list(query = query_string, variables = list("myVariantId" = rs_id))
  res <- tryCatch(
    # Perform POST request
    POST(url=base_url, body=post_body, encode='json'),
    error = function(e) e)
  if (inherits(res, "error")) {
    warning("error for gene ", sQuote(rs_id, FALSE), ": ",
            conditionMessage(res), call. = FALSE)
    res <- NULL
  } else if (status_code(res) != 200) {
    warning("abnormal return for gene ", sQuote(rs_id, FALSE), ": ",
            status_code(res), call. = FALSE)
    res <- NULL
  } else {
    #Export the data 
    res <- content(res)$data
    #content(res, "text")
  }
  res
})

json_data <- toJSON(alldata, force = T)
typeof(json_data)
write(json_data, "myJSON.json")
```

But i want to use it for a list with thousand rsIDs and export a jason in the simplest format.
Can we make any improvement regarding my script to make it easier in view and further usage of the elements of JSON? For example i would like to have for each rsId the corresponding variant ID (1_2909753_G_A) and gene id (ENSG00000215912) but to be able to see all those for all my data?

Comment: I believe the first step would be to define what constitutes a better visualization. I understand you want a to filter the value of rsID, variantID and Gene id. Is there only one value of variantID and Geneid for each rsID? If yes, would a table with rows rsID and columns variantID and Gene id suffice? Or do you have to keep it as JSON?

Comment: it would be ok to have such a table since each rsID corresponds to one variant and one GeneID for this query and this will help me  to organize my data for other queries. On the same time i want to keep the JSON format because in other queries it wont correspond only to one. I would appreciate if we could  see both solutions

Comment: I cannot give the full answer right now, but fromJSON() would transform the data into a data.frame, which would solve the table issue. If, you don't have a data.frame-compatible, it will output a list, which you can use the standard brackets to do extraction and simplification.